# Mounting a Windows fileshare - A file containing Emojis causes "Invalid Argument" error

Tags: file, centos, mounted-volumes

I have mounted a Windows file share in CentOs 8. I am mounting the drive by adding the following line to the /etc/fstab file:

```
//myservername/foldername /mount/test_share cifs user,uid=1000,rw,nocase,iocharset=utf16,suid,credentials=alocation/share_secret 0 0
```

I have tried both utf8 and utf16 as the iocharset.

There is a file in one of the fileshare folders with emojis in the name.

Unfortunately I get an "Invalid Argument" error whenever I try to do anything with the file. An ls-i command shows it as a messed up inode. See image.

[image: Manifestation of error]

Any ideas on how I could mount the windows file share to cater for this or any other work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just in case anyone else runs into this. The problem seems to have been specifying "rw" explicitly instead of allowing Samba and Active Directory to do their things in the background. It only manifested with filenames containing emojis for some reason I never figured out. The following mount worked:

```
//myservername/foldername /mount/test_share cifs user,uid=1000,suid,credentials=alocation/share_secret 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

BDH, Hope you are well.

A way forward here is to install a font that will render the unicode.

For me it was `yum install fonts-noto-color-emoji` and a reset of the terminal with `fc-cache -vf`

You can imagine my excitement when I found this post! I can also imagine you are in a place now where you care less about the answer.

See you round mate